# Multiple record selection while using StandardSetController

Tags: standardsetcontroller

Is there a way to implement multiple record selection with standard set controller varible without using wrapper class?

how to use **setSelected()** and **getSelected()**? Can we directly set selected records from VF page without making a roundtrip to controller[like actionFunctions]?

[image]